# Is it true that the spelling reform changed the meaning of 'War and Peace'?

Tags: орфография

I've seen copies of *War and Peace* with the old orthography.

1. Does the old form carry a different connotation or meaning than the new?
2. Is there a nuance in pronunciation that indicates awareness of this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it's not true.

Russian has two homonymous words (both pronounced *мир*) for *world* and *peace*. Currently, they are homographes as well, but in the old orthography they were written *мiръ* and *миръ*, accordingly. The is one more word, *мѵро* (chrism), spelt using the third version of Russian `i`, and in sg. gen. (*мѵра*, *мира*, *мiра*) all three words were homophones but not homographes.

There is an urban legend that the original meaning of the title was *War and the World*, not *War and Peace* which was lost after the reform.

All known publications have the title spelt as *Война и миръ*. There was a typo in *Brockhaus & Efron*, the largest Russian encyclopaedia of the time, which is possibly the source for the legend:

[image]

Note that the bottom line has the title written correctly.

[Here](http://www.peace-and-world.narod.ru/) you can read more about this (in Russian).

Vladimir Mayakovsky wrote a poem in 1915 which was titled *Война и мiръ*, a pun on the title of Tolstoy's work. The pun was lost with the orthography reform.

Comment: This site also features a cover of the original pre-reform publication of the novel http://www.artlebedev.com/mandership/125/